# How to Embed a Table in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been writing a GUI in Python 3 using PyQt5.

I am having trouble with trying to embed a table in PyQt's QMainWindow Class.

In the code below, I have two classes - one controlling the window (with object type QMainWindow) and another (with object type QWidget) controlling the table. I know the code is generating my main window and table as they pop up in two separate windows. What I am trying to do is embed the table in the main window with the button.

Like in the image below:

Floating Window Issue

[image]

What am I forgetting to do or not including? Thank you for the help.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class UserInterface(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UserInterface, self).__init__()
        self.TaskBar()
        self.Buttons()
        self.tabler = MyTable()

    def TaskBar(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("MyWindow")
        self.setGeometry(QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry())

    def Buttons(self):
        close_button = QPushButton("Close", self)
        close_button.resize(100, 50)
        close_button.move(100, 900)
        close_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font-size : 24px}")
        close_button.clicked.connect(sys.exit)

class MyTable(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTable, self).__init__()
        self.Table()

    def Table(self):
        self.mytable()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def mytable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0 , QTableWidgetItem("Hello"))
        self.tableWidget.move(300, 300)


def Main():
    qapplication_constructor = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = UserInterface()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(qapplication_constructor.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every QMainWindow must have a central widget.  You can set another widget as the central widget of the QMainWindow class.  You will however need to arrange the button differently so that it can be added to the correct layout.  Something like this:

```
class UserInterface(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(UserInterface, self).__init__()
        self.TaskBar()
        self.Buttons()

        self.table_widget = MyTable()

        close_button = QPushButton("Close", self)
        close_button.resize(100, 50)
        close_button.move(100, 900)
        close_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font-size : 24px}")
        close_button.clicked.connect(sys.exit)

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        layout.addWidget(close_button)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

This can be arranged differently depending on how you want to set the grid layout.  If the grid layout does not suite your needs, there are several available.

Comment: This was similar to a previous attempt I made but applying your fix, I still run into the same problem: the table now takes up the entire window and I cannot see the button. What I am trying to do is partition the table inside the window so I can still interact with buttons. Any thoughts? I attempted to resize the table using the resize method but no luck.

Comment: @TheCedarPrice Yes, I have changed my answer to provide a different solution that will allow this.

Comment: Nearly there! Now, I just don't want the button to resize with the table as I want to add other buttons to the right side of the table. I'd rather have the table embedded in the full side window rather than defining the window. Is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: Using QGridLayout you can specify what row and column you want items in and customize the way the widget will look.  [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) is the documentation page for QGridLayout.  The examples are in c++, but it should be pretty easily translated to python.

Comment: Perfect! I felt like I was missing something somewhere - didn't realize that was in the documentation. Been exploring the documentation for hours and somehow missed it. Thanks for the help @MalloyDelacroix!